# Is it possible to deny access to the SVN trunk, except for any merges from a branch

Tags: svn, branch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to lock SVN trunk except for merges from branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171174/how-to-lock-svn-trunk-except-for-merges-from-branch)

I'd like to configure SVN for our development team to enforce:

1) All developers must work on a branch until they are happy to commit a changeset to the trunk
2) To prevent developers working directly on the trunk I'd like to disallow direct commits to the trunk unless it's carried out through a merge?

Is this possible?